# Exposing a webservice API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a iPhone application that contains a test. However at this point all the questions are static, meaning that I have to update the app to fix errors. I have now made an Rails application so I can administrate them on the web and I want the app to be able to connect to the web service API (JSON) I am making.

I want the app to be able to update all the questions locally stored when a user updates the app so it is usable without an active internet connection.

My models in the Rails application are Question, Answer and Category. Question has many answers, and a question has and belongs to many categories.

I am unsure what I do next, and if this sounds crazy. I am thinking on giving the user the list of all questions with their belonging associations in JSON format. What do I do with the join table categories_questions that only hold foreign keys. And I have not understood how you can expose objects with associations in JSON format.

Help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this is to embed the associations into the parent model's JSON. Using a gem like [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/) will make this very easy to do.